# Remove dashes in xml tag only with regex

Tags: regex, xml, tags

I have to mange decoded XML files with few corruptions and I'm trying to fix them programmatically.

One of them is that I have, for example, an opening tag  with its closing tag corrupted

So, I need to remove the dash between word (**\w** in regex because it can contains numbers also) which are enclosed in **<>** characters

I've build this regex expression

```
(?<=\w)-(?=\w)
```

But it matches EVERY dash enclosed between **\w** . I need to match just the ones which are enclosed in **<>**:

```
<text-numbers>
```

Could you help me? 
Thank you very much in advance

Andrea

Comment: Try replacing `(\G(?!^)|</?)(\w*)-` with `$1$2`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, But it gives me error due to the /? I'm testing the regex here https://regex101.com/r/ob6CtF/2

Comment: I am also testing there - [no errors](https://regex101.com/r/MU5wuM/1). Test in the target environment.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906968/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest

```
(\G(?!^)|</?)(\w*)-
```

Replace with `$1$2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MU5wuM/1).

**Details**

- `(\G(?!^)|</?)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern): either the end of the previous match or `<` with an optional `/` after it (in case you define the pattern inside a regex literal with `/` as delimiters, escape `/` as `\/`)
- `(\w*)` - Group 2 (`$2` in the replacement pattern): zero or more word chars
- `-` - a hyphen.